# Prove that $I^2$ is principal.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

> Consider the ideal $I=(2,\sqrt{-10})$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-10}]$. Prove that $I^2$ is principal.

My Try:

$I^2=(4,-10,2\sqrt{-10})$. I tried to prove that $I^2=(\sqrt{-10})$. But failed. Is my claim correct? Can anybody please help me how to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $I^{\cdot2}=(2)$.  Note that $I^{\cdot2}$ contains $(4,-10)=(2)$.  On the other hand, every element of $I^{\cdot2}$ is clearly a multiple of $2$.

Comment: Why is $2\sqrt{-10}$ not a generator of $I^2$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this kind of questions.  For example, $2$ can be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ as an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ since there exists a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $2$ that generates $\mathbb{Z}$ (e.g., $\{2,3\}$).  Of course, there exists a subset of $I^{\cdot 2}$ with $2\sqrt{-10}$ in it such that this set generates $I^{\cdot 2}$.

Comment: I proved that $I^{\cdot 2}\supseteq(2)$ and $I^{\cdot 2}\subseteq (2)$, if that is what you are asking.